# delphi adoquery filter with listbox items

Tags: sql-server, delphi, filter, listbox

this is final but already not filter
anyone has idea about my filter problem

```
begin
adoquery1.SQL.CLEAR;
adoquery1.SQL.Add('select * FROM gunsonu ');
adoquery1.SQL.Add('where TARIH like :TRH');
adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('TRH').Value:=(PlannerDatePicker1.text);

for i := 0 to form3.ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
adoquery1.SQL.Add(' and VLIM <> '+QuotedStr(form3.ListBox1.items[i]));
end;
adoquery1.Open;
frxReport1.ShowReport(true);
```

Comment: When you say 'cant' you mean that your code executes, but adoquery1 doesn't return any rows?  The most like reason for that is that your listbox items doesn't contain any '%' wildcards.  If it doesn't, it works as is you have an '=' sign instead of the 'like'.

Comment: Also, if the columns you are trying to match against the listbox items are character columns, you should surround "form3.ListBox1.items[i]" by "QuotedStr()"

Comment: i try like it but it is already filter empty :(


begin
adoquery1.SQL.CLEAR;
adoquery1.SQL.Add('select * FROM gunsonu ');
adoquery1.SQL.Add('where TARIH like :TRH');
adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('TRH').Value:=(PlannerDatePicker1.text);

for i := 0 to form3.ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
adoquery1.SQL.Add(' and VLIM = '+ QuotedStr(form3.ListBox1.items[i]));
end;
adoquery1.Open;
frxReport1.ShowReport(true);
end;

Comment: Please add that code to your question,  it shoulld be in there, not in a comment.  And, show the values in your listbox, because it looks like you are trying to match a data row against several different values in the VLIM column (because of the ' and '), which is probably not what you intend.

Comment: so MartynA! do you have any idea, i have problem and i cant fix it

Comment: Yes.  Just do what I say in my answer.  That way **always** works.

Comment: Btw, do you get some rows returned if you comment out your "for ..." block?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to set up queries from a Delphi app against an MS Sql Server isn't to keep modifying code in the app that constructs the query until running it returns the results you're hoping for.  One of the problems with the Delphi rapid compile/run cycle is that it encourages trial and error, which is
no substitute for getting things working properly.

It's better to separate the SQL-constructing task from the coding one for two reasons:

1. The Sql Server client-side utilities (e.g. Sql Server Management Studio or the old ISql/W "Query Analyzer") are better tools for the Sql-construction task, they have access to the server's execution plan, profiler, etc.  But if you don't have one of those available, over the years, Delphi has included some kind of "Data Explorer" utility to run queries against a variety of servers - in recent XE versions, there's a Firedac one under `FireDac | Explorer` from the IDE menu.
2. Using one of those tools, you have the Sql query which is actually sent to the server right on the screen in front of you.  A frequent source of error when trying to set the Sql up in Delphi code, especially for a beginner, is that the Sql query sent to the server isn't necessarily what you assume it is.  Judging by the examples that appear in qs on SO, they're frequently riddled with syntactic or semantic errors, especially when the Sql is supposed to contain quotation marks (the Delphi IDE's Watch and Evaluate windows don't provide a good form for viewing Sql).  Creating the query in a Sql querying tool, you get the chance to see exactly what the query is, and to get feedback from the tool regarding syntax errors, etc.
3. It's easier using those tools to experiment with the best way to parameterize your query.

What's the point of 3?  Well, one thing is that parameterized queries are generally better optimized by the server than an ad hoc one, though admittedly not all queries can be expressed in a parameterized form  (e.g. you can't parameterize which column or table you're querying against).  The other thing is that it helps minimise your exposure to Sql-Injection (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Once you've got your query working as you're expecting in a client-side Sql tool like those above is the time to write the code to execute it from your Delphi app, not before.